# React trigger validation of field when another field is changed

Tags: reactjs

I have a form whith lengths and its number of individuals:
[image]

```
<form>{/* simplified code */}
{lengths.map((l, idx) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                value={l.length}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    editLength(idx, e);
                    validateLength(e);
                }}
            />
            <input
                value={l.number_individuals}
                onChange={(e) => editLength(idx, e)}
            />
            <button><UiButtonIconAdd /></button>
            <button><UiButtonIconDelete /></button>
        </div>
    );
})}
```

I have created a validation rule to avoid repeated lenthgs. When one lenght is changed but previously exists, the validation rule and the report validity are triggered, highlighting  the field:
[image]

```
/**
 * Validate lenght
 * @param {event} e onChange event
 * @returns In case of errors in length, show report validity.
 */
const validateLength = (e) => {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");

    if (lengthsExists(e.target.value) === true) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("This length already exists.");
    }

    return e.target.reportValidity();
};
```

But the issue I have is when, instead of fix the higlighted length, is fixed the length stored before:
[image]

I can't figure out how to force to re-evaluate the validation rule of the original length. I thought to trigger the setCustomValidity() from one input to other one, but I can't find the way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your input you can use the **return value** of the `validateLength` function

```js
<input
  value={l.length}
  onChange={(e) => {
    const isValid = validateLength(e);
    if (isValid === true) editLength(idx, e);
  }}
/>
```